# How to retrieve only non-negative values in a args list(comprehension)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

#How should I eliminate those string elements like "4" and "5"? #

The ideal output or results should be like below:

```
>>> filter_positives_from_args(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3)
    [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> filter_positives_from_args(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, '4', '5')
    [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> filter_positives_from_args(-3, -2, -1, False, True, 2, 3, '4', '5')
    [False, True, 2, 3]
```

My code:

```
def filter_positives_from_args(*args) -> list:
ans = [p for p in args if int(p) >= 0]
return(list(filter(None,ans)))
```

My output:

```
>>> print(filter_positives_from_args(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3))
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print(filter_positives_from_args(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, '4', '5'))
[1, 2, 3, '4', '5']
>>> print(filter_positives_from_args(-3, -2, -1, False, True, 2, 3, '4', '5'))
[True, 2, 3, '4', '5']
```

How to solve this problem？

Comment: Also, minor technicality, "positive" generally means non-negative *and* non-zero, i.e., strictly greater than zero. Your function would be more appropriately named `filter_non_negative_args` or something along those lines, if you plan to include zero and False.

Comment: There are no "kwargs" (keyword arguments) here - this syntax is normally called "vargs" or "var-args", short for "variable-length arguments".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to also check the type of each argument:

```py
def filter_non_negatives(*args):
    valid_types = {bool, int, float, complex}
    return [p for p in args if type(p) in valid_types and p >= 0]
```

Note that I've changed the name of the argument to be more accurate, as explained in my comment.

Comment: it might make sense to use `isinstance` here, which is intended to check against multiple types. `p for p in args if isinstance(p, valid_types) and p >= 0`

Comment: Maybe. If OP wants to consider parent classes. If they want to filter for specific types though, it's better to use `type()`, since `isinstance` considers parent classes.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach just using `try catch` mechanism:

```
def filter_positives_from_args(*data):
    out = []
    for d in data:
        try:
            if d >= 0:
                out.append(d)
        except Exception as ex:
            pass
    return out
print (filter_positives_from_args(-3, -2, -1, False, True, 2, 3, '4', '5'))
print (filter_positives_from_args(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, '4', '5'))
```

Output:

```
[False, True, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```